# Head First Servlets and JSP and the Java EE 6 Web Component Developer exam

Tags: jakarta-ee

im considering doing the Java EE 6 Web Component Developer Certified exam, but frankly cannot afford the course that is associated with it. The "Head First Servlets and JSP: Passing the Sun Certified Web Component Developer Exam" book claims to serve as sufficient material for learning and passing the material in the above exam. It does however relate to the J2EE 1.5 Sun Certified Web Component Developer (SCWCD) exam. Does anyone know whether the coverage would be sufficient for the aforementioned exam, or at least serve a coverage for the vast bulk of the assessable content?

Comment: Just do a side-by-side comparison of the topics covered by the Head First textbook with [the SCWCD syllabus](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&get_params=dc:D77750) and see where the gaps are. You might be able to fill it with outside resources on the web

Comment: thanks will do that!